# How to read lines from a file as well as from std::cin?

Tags: c++

I'm writing a program, which takes the lines of text to work with from the file, the name of which the user passes as an argument, e.g. `program <name of the file>`. But if the name is not provided, the input is taken dynamically from `std::cin`. What I've tried:

1. Redirecting the buffer (somewhy causes segfault)

```cpp
if (argc == 2) {
    std::ifstream ifs(argv[1]);
    if (!ifs)
        std::cerr << "couldn't open " << argv[1] << " for reading" << '\n';
    std::cin.rdbuf(ifs.rdbuf());
}

for (;;) {
    std::string line;
    if (!std::getline(std::cin, line)) // Here the segfault happens 
        break;
```

2. Creating a variable, in which the input source is stored

```cpp
std::ifstream ifs;
if (argc == 2) {
    ifs.open(argv[1]);
    if (!ifs)
        std::cerr << "couldn't open " << argv[1] << " for reading" << '\n';
} else
    ifs = std::cin;  // Doesn't work because of the different types

for (;;) {
    std::string line;
    if (!std::getline(ifs, line))
        break;
```

Now I'm thinking of doing something with file structures/descriptors. What to do?

**UPD:** I would like to have the possibility to update the input source in the main loop of the program (see below).

Comment: write your code in a function that takes an `ostream&` and output to that.  Then you can just pass to that function the stream you wish it to use.

Comment: Write a function that accepts a `std::istream &` and reads from that stream.   If your program needs to read from `std::cin`, then pass `std::cin` to that function.   If your program needs to read from a file, then open that file as an `std::ifstream` and pass that stream to your function.

Answer (score 4):

The seg fault in your first example is due to a dangling pointer; right after you call `std::cin.rdbuf(ifs.rdbuf())`, `ifs` is destroyed.
You should do what @NathanOliver suggests and write a function which takes an `istream&`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

void foo(std::istream& stream) {
  std::string line;
  while (std::getline(stream, line)) {
    // do work
  }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  if (argc == 2) {
    std::ifstream file(argv[1]);
    foo(file);
  } else {
    foo(std::cin);
  }
}
```

Comment: You can not use: `foo(std::ifstream(argv[1]));` as this creates a temporary variable that will not bind to a non const lvalue reference (ie. `std::istream&`). So you should create a local automatic variable that you can then pass as a reference to the fucntion.

Comment: Better to do the read and test for OK in a single line. prefer to use `while(std::getline())`

Comment: Fixed it for you :-)

Comment: thanks, I implemented my current solution likewise. But what if I want to update my input source in the `foo` function? how to do it without recursion?

Comment: @nuts_eater: You would have to use something other than a reference (ie. something that looks like a reference but allows you to change what it refers to). Have a look at `std::ref`